# representing of expectation for submatrices

Tags: probability, matrices, expected-value, random-graphs, random-matrices

Consider a matrix
$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} & a_{15} & a_{16} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} & a_{25} & a_{26} 
\end{pmatrix},
$$
in which sum of the elements of each colon is zero and $a_{i,j}=\pm1$.
Suppose also that $E(A)=C$.

Define sub-matrices $A_1=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12}\\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{pmatrix}$,
$A_2=\begin{pmatrix}
 & a_{13} & a_{14}\\
& a_{23} & a_{24} 
\end{pmatrix}$, $A_3=\begin{pmatrix}
 & a_{15} & a_{16} \\
 & a_{25} & a_{26} 
\end{pmatrix}$.
Is it possible to represent expectations of $A_1, A_2, A_3$ through $E(A)=C$?

Comment: Just take the corresponding submatrices of $C$.

Comment: Thank you, you mean that $E(A)=E(A_1)+E(A_2)+E(A_3)$ even though there is a dependence in the colums?

Comment: Maybe I'm confused about what you're doing. Shouldn't $E(A)$ be a $2\times 6$ matrix and $E(A_i)$ be $2\times2$ matrices?